# Understanding Two-Dimensional Ising Model Lattice in High Temperature Expansion

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, lattice-model

**TLDR**

I would like to have a simple way of understanding how counting works with the 2D ising model and what the general simplification schemes that I could use are.

**Background**

I have been trying to simplify the partition function in the [high-temperature limit for the 2D ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-lattice_Ising_model#High-temperature_expansion).

Let's define the hamiltonian for our 2D Ising model:

$\mathcal{H}=-J \sum_{<ij>} \sigma_i \sigma_j$

where the sum is over all possible pairs of nearest neighbors. This means the sum for large lattices has $2N$ terms ($N$ is the number of lattice points).

We can define the partition function as:

$\mathcal{Z}=Tr e^{-\beta \mathcal{H}}=\sum_{\{\sigma_k={\pm 1}\}}e^{\beta J \sum_{<ij>} \sigma_i \sigma_j} = \sum \prod e^{\beta J \sigma_i \sigma_j}$

where $\{\sigma_k=\pm 1 \}$ means we sum over all possible spin combinations. I'm sorry the equation looks kind of messy.

Then we may expand the $e^{\beta J \sigma_i \sigma_j}$ term:

$e^{\beta J \sigma_i \sigma_j} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (J \beta \sigma_i \sigma_j)^n$

Plugging back into $\mathcal{Z}$:

$\mathcal{Z}= \sum \prod e^{\beta J \sigma_i \sigma_j} = \sum_{\{\sigma_k\}} \prod_{<ij>} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (J \beta \sigma_i \sigma_j)^n$

I have no idea how to simplify this further. I believe I am somehow supposed to make use of the trace for the pauli spins (e.g. $\sum_{\sigma_k=\pm 1} \sigma_k^n$ is 0 when $n$ is odd and $2$ when $n$ is even).

**Question**

What kind of general identities can I use to simplify calculations for the 2D ising model, and how would I go about tackling this high temperature expansion problem? I also understand that in order to finally solve the partition function, I would need to understand exactly how to deal with the nearest neighbor product sum.

Comment: Technically speaking, what you are doing is deriving the random-current representation of the Ising model. You can extract the usual high-temperature expansion by a partial resummation, but this is not the simplest way to proceed. What you should do is write $\exp(\beta J \sigma_i\sigma_j) = \cosh(\beta J)(1+\sigma_i\sigma_j\tanh(\beta J))$ and then expand the product over the pairs $i,j$.

Comment: In both cases, the next step is indeed to take out of the sum over σ everything that is not dependent on σ. You then get something of the form $\sum_n \sum_\sigma \prod_i \sigma_i^{n_i} = \sum_n \prod_i \sum_{s=\pm 1} s^{n_i}$, where the sum is over collections of numbers $(n_{ij})$ indexed by pairs of neighbors (with $n_{ij}\in\mathbb{N}$ for your expansion and $n_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ for the high-temperature expansion) and I have set $n_i=\sum_{j\sim i} n_{ij}$. This can now be easily evaluated.

Comment: Note that this is described in detail in many textbooks. For example, see Section 3.7.3 in [this one](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html) (and Section 3.10.6 for the random-current expansion).

Comment: Oops, a typo in my second comment above: it should read $\sum_n a_n \sum_\sigma \prod_i \sigma_i^{n_i} = \sum_n a_n \prod_i \sum_{s=\pm 1} s^{n_i}$, where the $a_n$ are (explicit) coefficients incorporating all the $\sigma$-independent factors.